# How to use @JacksonInject(useInput= OptBoolean.FALSE)

Tags: java, jackson

About useInput,I've read from some article

> "useInput: It is Boolean and decides whether matching input value is used for annotated property or not. If the value is false, input value will be ignored. If the value is true, input value will override injected value. Default value of useInput is default that has true value."

My question:

### What does the "input value" and "inject value" mean?

Consider below code:

```
public class Writer {
    private Integer id;
    @JacksonInject(useInput = OptBoolean.TRUE)
    private String name;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String jsonData = "{\"id\":111,\"name\":\"Ju\"}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        InjectableValues.Std injectableValues = new InjectableValues.Std();
        injectableValues.addValue(String.class, "Default Value");
        mapper.setInjectableValues(injectableValues);
        Writer writer = mapper.readValue(jsonData, Writer.class);
        System.out.println(writer);
    }
 ....get set....
}
```

After deserializing the value of "name" property is always "Ju",whether OptBoolean is TRUE or FALSE ,so what does "OptBoolean" means? And how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

When Jackson comes to inject a value into a property, it can determine the value to inject based on two factors:

1. the type of the property
2. an arbitrary string id

this way, you can decide that all `String` properties will be injected with `"Default Value"` but one specific `String` property will be injected with `"Specific Value"`. to do that, you specify the String id as the annotation's value, and use [`injectableValues.addValue()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/InjectableValues.Std.html#addValue-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) that receives a `String` as 1st arg (not a `Class`)

the `UseInput` arg is meant for cases where although you specify annotation's value, you can decide if it will be used or ignored (reverting back to type-based injection) this is useful in case you do not have access to the source code (for example, in a 3rd party library) and then you can use Jackson's mixin feature to override the annotation